# Windows SharePoint Services vs. Microsoft Office SharePoint Server?

Tags: sharepoint, moss, comparison, wss

There's Windows SharePoint Services (WSS) and then there is Microsoft Office SharePoint Server (MOSS).  MOSS considerably more expensive than WSS (which ships as part of Microsoft Server licensing).

My question is: what does MOSS do that makes it *worth* the extra cost?

..and does [Microsoft Search Server](http://www.microsoft.com/Enterprisesearch/) not compete with the [Business Data Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms563661.aspx) (BDC)?

Edit: The feature comparision page is helpful in illustrating the numerous features that MOSS has and WSS does not.  By the looks of it, most of MOSS's feature set is Enterprise oriented.

How would you describe the differences (or additional benefits) of MOSS over WSS in a couple of sentences?  In essence, what are the "big ticket" items in MOSS (and not in WSS)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About WSS vs MOSS:

- WSS in not a portal, it's only a collaborative plateform (there are no publishing features in WSS)
- MOSS allows you to use user profils, not WSS
- Search functionalities are cheap in WSS compare to MOSS (but you can extend them using Search Server Express)
- Many others: Infopath, BDC, Additional WebParts, Additional site and list templates

About Search Server and BDC: They do not compete.

Search Server is the MOSS search engine striped out. So you have only search functionalities (you can index SharePoint, WebSite, FileSystem).

The BDC (Business Data Catalog) allows you to view an external business data source, such as a SQL database (not necessarily SQL Server, it can be Oracle, MySQL....) or webservices. You'll be able to view data in your portal, and integrate this data to any of your list.
The BDC also allows you to index this content source if you have SharePoint Enterprise Edition.

Answer (score 4):

Don't assume that WSS is free in all deployment scenarios.  We got a nice wake up call when we deployed WSS in a client-facing extranet configuration.  One "main site" w/ a bunch of segregated, client sub-sites.  Turns out we needed to buy an "intranet license" (can't remember the exact name) for the OS.  This is different from the SharePoint internet connector - it actually lets you use Win 2003 w/ an unlimited number of internet users.  Not hugely expensive, but it was a couple thousand dollars we weren't expecting on paying...

Comment: Yeah this is something which can go undetected unfortunately.  They have full time positions at Microsoft just to make heads or tails of the licensing mumbo jumbo :(  No one has voted up this question.. it seems popular enough!

Answer (score 2):

Whether it's *worth* the extra cost really depends on how many of the added features MOSS brings to the table that you're actually going to *use*.

The following comparison page by Microsoft will definitely help to answer your question.

[Microsoft Office SharePoint Server 2007 Edition Comparison](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointtechnology/FX101758691033.aspx?ofcresset=1)

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot built in to WSS but MOSS has a ton of extra stuff as referenced in the other answer.

On the second part of your question.. Search server and Business Data Connector are quite different.. Search server is about finding things... BDC is about merging datasources to be able to use them easily in sharepoint or in connected excel sheets etc.. The focus is on what is being delivered-- search results or data.

Answer (score 0):

I would say if you just need a few collaboration sites for a few internal groups, then wss is just fine.  It is when you start using SharePoint for enterprise level applications and as a primary platform for development that you should consider MOSS.